# Getting an error in cross site scripting within jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am working on a project where am getting an error of Cross Site Scripting.. In a JSP file there is a code line below

```
var selSubArea = document.adminForm.subjAreaId.options[document.adminForm.subjAreaId.selectedIndex].text;
```

Anyone having idea how to resolve it. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

I have already tried to use different Encoding techniques but not working...
for eg. Encode.forHtml, Encode.forJavascript, COV Security, fn EscapeXML.....

```
var selRole = document.adminForm.appnRoleId.options[document.adminForm.appnRoleId.selectedIndex].text;
var selSubArea = document.adminForm.subjAreaId.options[document.adminForm.subjAreaId.selectedIndex].text;
var selRoleID = document.adminForm.appnRoleId.options[document.adminForm.appnRoleId.selectedIndex].value;
var selSubAreaID = document.adminForm.subjAreaId.options[document.adminForm.subjAreaId.selectedIndex].value;
```

I am getting this Cross Site scripting issue with only texts Inputs.. and these are actually Dropdowns..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is your trying to stop someone entering data XSS into your drop down menu from your question.

Maybe have the selected Index's info hard coded on the server/application and just send the index.

```
var selSubArea = document.adminForm.subjAreaId.selectedIndex;
```

If the index doesn't match indexes on the server/application, just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..I'll try to use it.. 

Comment: Can you take look at this [https://stackoverflow.com/q/55927975/11352304]

Comment: Hi, i tried to use  `var selSubArea = document.adminForm.subjAreaId.selectedIndex;` but its only giving ID...is there any other way to use both at same time "option" & "SelectedIndex"...

Comment: Your ID should match your option on your server. How have you got your server side set up. It Should take Selected index and match it with the option