# Getting XSS error in one of Controller from an application

Tags: java

I am working on a code in which there are several controllers. In few of controllers am getting a **Cross Site Scripting** error on main method line.

```
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Can you please let me know what to check and how to resolve this issue of XSS. I tried to sanitize it using `StringEscapeUtils.EscapeHtml` in few controllers and it's working, but rest are still showing same issue.

I have also tried to use `EncodeHtml`, `EncodeJavascript` to encode few lines(inputs).

```
String eid = Encode.forJavaScript((String) request.getSession().getAttribute(RConstants.EID));
```

Please let me know any of other solutions you ever used with these kind of issues. Any help must appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: The other one was PHP @Pratik, i am not accustom to java. But i'll try. Can you not use `StringEscapeUtils.EscapeHtml` for all of them?

Comment: I am not using it for all of them..But i tried it cause its working with one of controller..

Comment: Hi, still struggling with these errors.. Can you please help me out with this.. any other suggestions or informations I can use to resolve it..?